# ¿Como hacer para que mis controles en el formulario no se muevan solos en la etapa de diseño (C#)?

Tags: c#

Estoy en la etapa de diseño de un formulario de un sistema de informacion, ahí en la imagen se puede observar como el GroupBox se recorrió solo a la izquierda, esto hace que se desacomode el diseño inicial... alguien podría indicarme como evitar esto.

[image: formulario visual studio c#]

Comment: La mejor manera es hacerlo usando [`Grid`](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/)

Comment: Hola, podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resolvio tu problema, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para bloquear todos los controles del formulario:

Clic derecho arriba del mismo y se selecciona la opción **Lock Controls**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es un solo componente ej. un botón, clic derecho sobre el botón y se selecciona igualmente la opción **Lock Controls**.

Si quisieras bloquear todos los controles de un componente contenedor ej. un **Panel** o un **GroupBox**, clic derecho sobre el componente contenedor y se selecciona igualmente la opción **Lock Controls**.

Comment: gracias, ese ultimo comentario me sirvio...

Comment: Hola @Edson, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te fue util, gracias